# How can I get the Content-Length from service in WCF methods?

Tags: wcf

My service uses `WCFbinding` of type `wshttpbind`.

How can I get the `Content-Length`?

Comment: Why do you need to know the physical length of the entire SOAP message?

Comment: I want to record the data sizes where it`s from server to client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use this code in your operation:

```
MessageProperties properties = OperationContext.Current.IncommingMessageProperties;
var httpProperty = properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
int length = Int32.Parse(httpProperty.Headers["Content-Length"]);
```

**Edit:**

Response length is not known till the response data are serialized and message is formatted.  By the architecture this happens out of the service class itself. You can try to create custom MessageEncoder and get content length in overriden WriteMessage method.